# Can unseen faces in joined meshes be 'removed'?

Tags: edit-mode

I am wondering if it is possible to 'lose' those faces which end up 'inside' a model and never seen.
An example would be a 1 meter long rectangular mesh which when duplicated (or array applied) and brought together will still have 12 faces (6 for each mesh) yet we can only see 6 faces. Decimate cannot be used (to remove the unseen faces) without distortion.
I note that @moonboots responded to a similar question and suggested using the boolean modifier but I need some tuition on how. And would the modifier need to be applied to every join (I will be creating a girder bridge with a huge amount of girders)?

[added later]  I found a youtube tutorial which seems to answer my question is that correct?  [Blender - Remove Intersecting Geometry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kf16s5MPBLg)

Comment: Please upload a Blend file with a small section of your problem mesh so that we can have a look and offer suggestions. https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: My 'example' can be downloaded from this link https://mega.nz/file/Dhx1SIoK#Y3cBwAn1Mddmlj1ayfHpq-8i1liGDbwPRwK1ECbtvoA    it is two rectangle meshes moved together on the Y axis and joined (ctrl J). Decimate shows there are 12 faces yet only 6 are visible.

Comment: Here is an example of two sections of the side of a girder ramp. I created one section, joined it into a single object then duplicated it then moved the two sections together. Each section shows 24 faces (using decimate) yet joining the two sections into one object the decimate shows 48 faces yet many faces (eg the ends of each 'girder') are 'buried' inside other meshes (girders) which are unseen.  https://mega.nz/file/3xAyFLDT#0sFS4GqhAlQX_rvARBnXRdn2A7yk4t6BmHIa1Zyq1Uc

Comment: Firstly please use the official site to upload files in future not external ones! I put the link to blend-exchange.com in my previous comment! This isn't a tutorial site, but I think a lot of your problems stem from the fact that you're creating your meshes from several different parts and joining them rather than modelling them from a single object. For instance (apart from the diagonal girder) all of your mesh can be modelled from a single cube so you wont' get the overlap at top right. Also delete any faces which are going to be internal **before** you duplicate or array an object.

Comment: @John Eason Thanks I now realise that the link is not just a link to the 'stack'exchange. Yes I could create my bridge 'section' from one mesh but have no idea how to do that with diagonals.   And yes I always 'cleanup' an object before duplicating or applying the array modifier however I cannot remove 'future' internal faces (those faces which are the result of adjacent parts after using an array).  My girder bridge 'repeats' the same 'section' 15 times over the entire length. Still there are not many faces anyway but only used that as an example to describe the reason for the question.